# "Enable traces" is missing in Developer options android

Tags: android, systrace

I am trying to analyse my App's performance with systrace. But In developer options I could not find "Enable traces" in developer options as I saw in many of the tutorials.

I could see the Android version is 4.0.4 in About device.

Please help me how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "enable traces" debugging option was not introduced until Android 4.1. You'll need to use a different device to use this option.

Comment: Can't find Systrace option in Developer option - Debuging in Vivo Android 12 device
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75354227/cant-find-systrace-option-in-developer-option-debuging-in-vivo-android-12-dev