# Can't find Systrace option in Developer option - Debuging in Vivo Android 12 device

Tags: android, systrace

I've a Vivo Android 12, on which I want to take a systrace of my app. I just can't find the Systrace option as shown in the developer website - https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/tracing/on-device#set-up-tile

Here is a screerecord of me not able to find the systrace option -

[Not able to find systrace options in vivo android 12](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tgjOG4SD-G4HAr2kQafkat_pMTBMVmZK/view?usp=sharing)

Is there a workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a fair question to the phone's OEM (Vivo in this case). You may be able to use a virtual device in the emulator to try the System Tracing functionality.

Comment: okay @Shukang Z